# Why can't I use reverse DNS to create a java / gradle module on IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, project, naming

How exactly do I name an IntelliJ project, module, packages etc? I tried to name a module in reverse dns, but IntelliJ would not allow it, so I am obviously doing something wrong. Also, I'm confused between the difference between a Java Module and an IntelliJ Module.

Update: There was a bug with IntelliJ's Maven Artifactid, and a patch was released this month to fix it.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Does the issue still occur in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/?

Comment: This is runtime version, not IntelliJ IDEA version. There were known issues with the project/module name restrictions being incorrect in the recent IDE updates. Please check the version I linked.

Comment: Do you have the same issue in EAP or in the current release? If so, please share a screenshot showing which specific names are not accepted.

Comment: yes, the convention is using lowercase with dashes. however, if you insist to use CamelCase instead, it's not a problem either, just a warning which you can disable. And you tried to name a module in reverse dns, isn't it a lowercase? like "com.something.name"

Comment: @CrazyCoder You were right, there was a bug and updating worked. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292932. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA should accept dots in the names if you use the current release or EAP version. 2022.1 version [had a known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292932) preventing using dots in the project names.

[image: works]